# tcsh: search entire array for a variable

Tags: array, tcsh, csh

I am modifying a suite of scripts written in tcsh. Unfortunately, these scripts can't be rewritten because the program they interface with is also written in tcsh. I just want to get out of the way the idea that if I could rewrite these in BASH or literally any other language, I would.

As part of these scripts many of our variables are saved in arrays. My question is: Is there a way in tcsh where you can query if the content of a variable is present in an array (regardless of its position in the array) without using loops?

For example, I have the following array of valid ROI names:

```
set shortROI = {"lAmy_","mAmy_","A32p_","A32sg_"}
```

When the user executes the script they have an option to use a flag to say they want to redo processing for one or more *specific* ROIs from the options above. So like, if the flag is `-remake_ROI`, as part of calling the script they could add `-remake_ROI lAmy` or `-remake_ROI lAmy A32p_` to remake those ROIs only. I have a very large `while` loop currently processing all possible flags but the section relevant here looks like this:

```
set ac = 1
set redo_rois  = 0
set roi_proc_list = 

        while ( $ac <= $#argv )
        foreach roi_opt ( $shortROI )
            if ( "$argv[$ac]" == $roi_opt )
                @ redo_rois ++
                set roi_proc_list = ( $roi_proc_list $roi_opts )
            endif
        end
        @ ac ++
    end
```

`ac` is the command line argument count, `redo_rois` is the number of ROIs to re-process and `roi_proc_list` is the actual list to redo. I was wondering instead of the many loops, if there was something like `if ( "$argv[$ac]" == "$shortROI[*]" )` that would get the job done.

Thank anyone for their help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( " $shortROI " =~ *" $argv[$ac] "* ) then
   ...
endif
```

Example:

```
set list = (foo bar baz)

foreach a ($*)
        if(" $list " =~ *" $a "*) then
                echo "$a in list"
        else
                echo "$a NOT in list"
        endif
end
```

This may incorrectly return true if either the variable on the right side or any of the words from the list contain spaces. If you can decide on a character which cannot appear in either side (eg. `@`), you can replace the spaces with it in each word:

```
foreach a ($*:q)
        if(" $list:q:gas/ /@/ " =~ *" $a:q:as/ /@/ "*) then
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this - it's just what I was looking for. I appreciate the caveats about the spaces as well.

Comment: Great idea for how to handle spaces!  Using octal, you can substitute with a non-printable character instead of '@'.  I successfully used " $list:q:gas/ /\0177/ ", for example.